# Should I turn off or standby my encrypted phone to maximize lifespan

Tags: battery, standby

Should I turn my phone off at night or just lock it, to minimize battery usage and battery wear, and also wear to the flash memory? 
This question is similar to [Should I keep my Android tablets' power off or leave them on standby mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43894/should-i-keep-my-android-tablets-power-off-or-leave-them-on-standby-mode), but my phone's encrypted, so everytime it boots up it has to decrypt, which I'm guessing uses up quite a bit of battery to do and IO operations to the device storage.

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Which phone model are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I enable airplane mode at night to minimize battery usage. So the device doesn't require a boot when I'm ready to start the day. Just disable the airplane mode.

Airplane mode just disables radio signal (cellular services, bluetooth, etc), since it draws most battery juices.